# How to deform gltf mesh during runtime

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to distort a simple gltf disc via Three. I'm able to distort it on the first frame, but the mesh does not keep deforming, despite the Y coordinates being changed every frame. 
This is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>

<script type="module">
    import * as THREE from "../node_modules/three/build/three.module.js";
    import {GLTFLoader} from '../node_modules/three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';

    var camera, scene, renderer, controls;
    init();

    function init() {
        scene = new THREE.Scene();
        let container = new THREE.Object3D()
        const gltfLoader = new GLTFLoader();
        gltfLoader.load('gltf/disc.gltf', (gltf) => {
            const glScene = gltf.scene;
            container.add(glScene);
            scene.add( container );
            setUp()
            let disc = glScene.getObjectByName('disc');
    test(disc);

        });
    }

    function test (disc) {
        let k = 0;
        let r =100;
        disc.matrixAutoUpdate  = true

        let dbg=0;
        let position = disc.geometry.getAttribute('position');
        let count=position.count;



        /** HERE IS WHERE THE ACTION HAPPENS **/

        let go = () => {
            requestAnimationFrame(go);
            k += .1
            dbg++
            for (let i = 0; i < count; i++){
                if(dbg%90===1&&i===0){
                    console.log('y',position.getY(i))
                }
                let av=Math.sin(0.25*i+k) * r
                position.setY(i,av);
            }

            renderer.render( scene, camera );

        }// end go

        /**************************************/

        go();

    }


function setUp(){
    let width=window.innerWidth;
    let height=window.innerHeight;
    const color = 0xFFFFFF;
    const intensity = 2;
    const light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(color, intensity);
    light.name="directionalLight"
    light.castShadow=true;
    light.position.set(40, 15, 5);
    light.target.position.set(0, 0, 0);
    scene.add(light)

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50, width /height, .001, 8000)
    camera.position.set(580, 580, 40);
    camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
    renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    renderer.setClearColor(0xdedede, 1)
    renderer.autoClear = true
    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I've tried every combo, reasonable or not, of matrixAutoupdate=true, dynamic=true, etc etc, to no avail.
Any suggestions?

EDIT:
This is the list of things I tried, most of them taken from answers from forums, and seemed to resolve the issue, but not in this case. I used them both inside, outside, and both inside and outside the render loop. The list is:

```
disc.geometry.computeBoundingSphere();
disc.geometry.matrixAutoUpdate  = true;
disc.geometry.dynamic=true;
disc.geometry.needsUpdate = true
disc.geometry.attributes.position.needsUpdate = true;
disc.updateMatrixWorld(true);
position.needsUpdate = true;
```

EDIT 2:
Looks like the problem was with the gltf file itself, which was exported from cinema4D with its gltf exporter. Exporting the file to .dae and then using COLLADA2GLTF did the trick.

Comment: position.needsUpdate = true [?](https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-custom-buffergeometry.html), you need to set it every frame

Comment: @gman I tried that, no joy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `position.needsUpdate = true`;

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
#c {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
<script type="module">
import * as THREE from 'https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r115/build/three.module.js';
import {OrbitControls} from 'https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r115/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';
import {GLTFLoader} from 'https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r115/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';

  function test (disc) {
        let k = 0;
        let r =1;

        let dbg=0;
        let position = disc.geometry.getAttribute('position');
        let count=position.count;



        /** HERE IS WHERE THE ACTION HAPPENS **/

        let go = () => {
            k += .1
            dbg++
            for (let i = 0; i < count; i++){
                let av=Math.sin(0.25*i+k) * r
                position.setY(i,av);
            }
            position.needsUpdate = true;
        }// end go

       return go;
    }

function main() {
  const canvas = document.querySelector('#c');
  const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas});

  const fov = 45;
  const aspect = 2;  // the canvas default
  const near = 0.1;
  const far = 500;
  const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspect, near, far);
  camera.position.set(0, 1, 3);

  const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, canvas);
  controls.target.set(0, 1, 0);
  controls.update();

  const scene = new THREE.Scene();
  scene.background = new THREE.Color('black');

  {
    const skyColor = 0xB1E1FF;  // light blue
    const groundColor = 0xB97A20;  // brownish orange
    const intensity = 1;
    const light = new THREE.HemisphereLight(skyColor, groundColor, intensity);
    scene.add(light);
  }

  {
    const color = 0xFFFFFF;
    const intensity = 1;
    const light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(color, intensity);
    light.position.set(5, 10, 2);
    scene.add(light);
    scene.add(light.target);
  }

  let fn = () => {};
  {
    const gltfLoader = new GLTFLoader();
    gltfLoader.load('https://threejs.org/examples/models/gltf/Duck/glTF/Duck.gltf ', (gltf) => {
      const root = gltf.scene;
      scene.add(root);

     fn = test(root.getObjectByName('LOD3spShape'));
      

    });
  }

  function resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer) {
    const canvas = renderer.domElement;
    const width = canvas.clientWidth;
    const height = canvas.clientHeight;
    const needResize = canvas.width !== width || canvas.height !== height;
    if (needResize) {
      renderer.setSize(width, height, false);
    }
    return needResize;
  }

  function render() {
    if (resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer)) {
      const canvas = renderer.domElement;
      camera.aspect = canvas.clientWidth / canvas.clientHeight;
      camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    }
    
    fn();

    renderer.render(scene, camera);

    requestAnimationFrame(render);
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

main();
</script>
```